# codeigniter : i need to use session variable inside My_Lang.php

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

Give error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: MY_Lang::$session
>   Filename: core/MY_Lang.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll work but I think you need to load the session library inside `MY_Lang.php`:

```
$ci = &get_instance();
$ci->load->library("session");
```

then continue using:

```
$ci->session->userdata();
```

Comment: how are you using this class? can you provide some extra code?

Comment: https://github.com/dreamerslab/ci-i18n/blob/master/MY_Language.php
i am using this one
function MY_Language()
{
$ci = &get_instance();
$ci->load->library("session");
$segment = $ci->session->userdata('lang');
}

Comment: did you try changing `extends CI_Language` to `extends CI_Lang` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the session variable in from your controller. As the error shows session is not available in the lang class. In your controller do -

```
    str_replace (["{session_var}"],[$this->session->userdata("some_value")],$this->lang->line("some_lang_line"));
```

In your language file you would need to do:

```
    $lang["some_lang_line"]="your variable equals {session_var}";
```